# gnuplot date and file handling

Tags: date, file-io, gnuplot

How do I use dates in Gnuplot for data file retrieval? (as opposed to plotting the data)
I need to

- get today's date from the system - I use

```
DATE = `/usr/bin/date  "+%Y-%m-%d"` ;
```

- I need to print/echo the date in my script
- Insert that date into my script  in order to plot the correct data file

Should I rather use strftime?

Code:

```
set format x "             %d/%m-%H:%M"
DATE = `/usr/bin/date  "+%Y-%m-%d"` ;

#sprintf ""
${DATE} = sprintf("${DATE}")

if (exists("DATE")) print "DATE is defined :" ;"${DATE}";
     if (!exists("DATE")) print "DATE is not defined"

#print (${DATE},3,4)
```

then later in the script I need to insert the date and plot :

```
plot "/data/tmp/${DATE}.txt" using 1:11 title 'Battery Voltage' with lines
```

Basically - how do I point Gnuplot at the correct date-titled file?

Answer (score 2):

To assign the current date to the variable `DATE`, you can use the built-in gnuplot commands `strftime` and `time`:

```
DATE=strftime('%Y-%m-%d', time(0))
print DATE
```

Output:

```
2014-07-17
```

You could create your file path directly from `strftime` by adding in the rest of the path to the format string:

```
file = strftime('/some/dir/%Y-%m-%d.txt', time(0))
```

Alternatively you could use `sprintf` later on:

```
file = sprintf('/some/dir/%s.txt', DATE)
```

or just use concatenation:

```
file = '/some/dir/' . DATE . '.txt'
```

Rather than assigning the output of these commands to a variable, you could also use them directly in your `plot` line, for example:

```
plot sprintf('/some/dir/%s.txt', DATE) using 1:11 title 'Battery Voltage' with lines
```

Comment: Thank you Tom - is DATE = ${DATE}? How do I insert into

Comment: (continued) ..insert into - plot "/data/tmp/${DATE}.txt" using 1:11 title 'Battery Voltage' with lines

Comment: I've edited my answer to add some more detail. Hope that makes it clear.

Comment: The code works - thanks Tom. plot FILE using 1:4 title 'Barometric Pressure' with points. But when I parse the data through awk gnuplot complains : gnuplot> plot FILE using 1:4 title 'Barometric Pressure' with points, '< awk ''{y1 = y2; y2 = $4; if (NR > 1 && y2 - y1 >= 100) printf("\n") ; if (NR > 1 && y2 -y1 <= -100) printf("\n"); print}''using FILE 1:4 with linespoints'      I get      Need full using spec for x time data
gnuplot> awk: fatal: cannot open file `FILE' for reading (No such file or directory)

Comment: @user3778424 If the original problem is solved, then it would be better to accept my answer, upvote it if you found it useful and ask a new question. Then I (or someone else) can take a look at it in more detail.

Comment: @user3778424 I notice that you are using this answer in your more recent question. Don't forget to accept it by clicking the tick :)